# How do I get links that are AJAXy to replace the content inside an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So, I added to my AJAX links the name of the iframe, `target="name"`, but I think I might be erroring on the replacing part...

```
page.replace_html("section-content",:partial=>"/path/contents/edit",:object=>@content)
```

yeah, it's RoR, but that's not important... I think my selector isn't being found because that div is now in an iframe.

How to I select elements in an iframe?

I've tried `window.frames['name'].document` but I just get a document object that seems to have no methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.frames['name'].contentDocument.document`

Note: You must obey the same-origin policy.

For IE7 and lower, use:

`window.frames['name'].contentWindow.document`

P.S., you can use `document.getElementById('id')` instead of `window.frames['name']`